# How to run AStyle from inside Sublime?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, astyle

I already tried using the SublimeAStyle Package, but it didn't work. When I pressed the keys, the command would not fire (I checked in the console). Now I am trying to write my own key-shortcut to run the program on my source code. I have this:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+f"], "command": "exec", "args": { "cmd": ["C:\\Program Files\\AStyle\\bin\\astyle.exe", "${file_name}"]} }
```

but the `${file_name}` is not expanding to pass the file name to the command. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: make a build system

Comment: CudaText editor also has AStyle plugin, you may try if it works.

Comment: I would, but I'm already used to Sublime